# Next and Prev post link breaks code on last post

Tags: next-post-link

I have a problem with the following code  snippet that I found and adapted. Works well, except for the last post...as the last post does not have a "previous" post, this seems to bring up a problem and breaks the layout by adding a div in the wrong place...

I cant undestand what part is not working.If I check the 1st post of the blog, then , the snippet works well, without breaking... if someone could help me understand how to make the code render the results if there is no previous or next, dont show nothing.

```
<div id="cooler-nav" class="nextprevarea">
<h3 class="commentitle">More Underwater Media</h3>
<?php $prevPost = get_previous_post(false ,'1');
if($prevPost) {?>
<div class="nextprevleft nextprevcommon">
<?php $prevthumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($prevPost->ID, array(100,100) );?>
<?php previous_post_link('%link',"$prevthumbnail  <p>%title</p>", false , '1'); ?>
    </div>
<?php $nextPost = get_next_post(false ,'1');
if($nextPost) {?>
<div class="nextprevright nextprevcommon">
<?php $nextthumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($nextPost->ID, array(100,100) ); } ?>
<?php next_post_link('%link',"$nextthumbnail  <p>%title</p>", false , '1'); ?>
</div> 
<?php ?>
</div><!--#cooler-nav div -->
 <?php }  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Wasn't closed well

```
<div id="cooler-nav" class="navigation">
    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
        <h3>More Underwater Media</h3>
    </div>


<?php $prevPost = get_previous_post(true);
    if($prevPost) {?>
        <div class="nav-box previous">
            <div class="navig_thumb_wrapper">
                <?php $prevthumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($prevPost->ID, array(100,100) );?>
                <?php previous_post_link('%link',"$prevthumbnail", TRUE); ?>
            </div>
                <?php previous_post_link('%link',"<p>< %title</p>", TRUE); ?>

        </div>
<?php } ?>



<?php  $nextPost = get_next_post(true);
    if($nextPost) {?>
        <div class="nav-box next" style="float:right;">
            <div class="navig_thumb_wrapper">
                <?php $nextthumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($nextPost->ID, array(100,100) );?>
                <?php next_post_link('%link',"$nextthumbnail", TRUE); ?>
            </div>
                <?php next_post_link('%link',"<p>%title ></p>", TRUE); ?>

        </div>

<?php } ?>

</div>
```